# Orientational averaging of dipoles

Tags: optics, dipole-moment, nanoscience

I was reading a research paper where Quantum emitters with random dipole orientations are placed around a spherical nanoparticle.

Then during calculations averaging over orientations is performed using following relation.

$$\langle e_{j}^{\alpha}e_{j}^{\beta}e_{j}^{\gamma}e_{j}^{\delta} \rangle = \frac{1}{15}(\delta_{\alpha \beta}\delta_{\gamma\delta}+\delta_{\alpha \gamma}\delta_{\beta\delta}+\delta_{\alpha \delta}\delta_{\gamma\beta})$$

I tried to find a resource to help me understand how this averaging work, but couldn't find a useful resource for that.

And how this will change if all dipoles have dipole moments normal to the nanoparticle surface.

Comment: Which research paper? Always provide a reference - you never know when there is valuable context (like, say, the definition of the $e_j^\alpha$) that you didn't think to provide but which is necessary to provide an answer (or to make the answers as full as possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of a formula for an isotropic Cartesian tensor.
Isotropic means that it is invariant to any rotation of the coordinate system,
and such tensors turn up in a variety of physical situations.
If you do some research on Cartesian tensors you will find that the most general
isotropic fourth-rank Cartesian tensor can be written
$$
T_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta} = 
  A\,\delta_{\alpha\beta}\delta_{\gamma\delta} 
+ B\,\delta_{\alpha\gamma}\delta_{\beta\delta}
+ C\,\delta_{\alpha\delta}\delta_{\beta\gamma}
$$
with some constants $A$, $B$ and $C$ depending on the symmetry and the physics.
The result you quote is a special case for which
$A=B=C$,
which applies
because the indices $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, $\delta$ 
on the left hand side of your formula can be switched around arbitrarily
without changing the result.
The Kronecker deltas in your answer are basically expressing this fact.
We shall see shortly that the prefactor is $A=\frac{1}{15}$.
Fortunately, it is possible to explain this without going deep into tensor analysis.

Your formula is an *isotropic average* of a product of four terms,
each being a component of a unit vector
$\mathbf{e}_i=(e_{i}^x,e_{i}^y,e_{i}^z)$.
Each superscript $\alpha, \beta$ etc. can be $x$ or $y$ or $z$.
The angle brackets on the left of your expression
refer to this *isotropic orientational average*.
In principle you could evaluate any of these averages by expressing the components in polar angles
$$\mathbf{e}_i=(\sin\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\theta)$$ and performing the average.
The volume element is $\sin\theta d\theta d\phi$,
and for an isotropic distribution,
the integral is simply normalized by the solid angle $4\pi$.
For example
$$
\langle e_{i}^z e_{i}^z e_{i}^z e_{i}^z \rangle = 
\frac{1}{4\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi \int_0^{\pi} \sin\theta d\theta \cos^4\theta = \frac{1}{5}.
$$
This answer agrees with your formula 
($\alpha=\beta=\gamma=\delta=z$ and each Kronecker term contributes $1$).
The same result will come if all the indices are $x$, or all $y$.
That particular one is easy, but the more general case can get a bit tedious.
Therefore I'm going to derive the result using a few simple symmetry relations.

To reduce the clutter I am going to write $\mathbf{e}_i=(x,y,z)$ and remember $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ (normalization).
It should be obvious that $\langle x\rangle = \langle y\rangle = \langle z\rangle=0$
because in the isotropic averaging $-x$ turns up just as often as $+x$ and the terms cancel.
In fact,
whenever an index appears an odd number of times, the orientational average will vanish.
For the second-rank cases,
for the same reason,
$\langle xy\rangle =\langle yz\rangle=\langle xz\rangle=0$.
By symmetry 
(for example, 
rotating the coordinate system by 120 degrees about the $(1,1,1)$ direction so as to interchange $x\rightarrow y\rightarrow z$)
we see that $\langle x^2\rangle =\langle y^2\rangle =\langle z^2\rangle$.
These three terms are all equal to each other, and they all add up to $1$,
so they must all be equal to $\frac{1}{3}$.
Putting these results all together gives 
$$
\langle 
e_{i}^\alpha e_{i}^\beta
\rangle = \frac{1}{3} \delta_{\alpha\beta} .
$$
This is a simpler example of the kind of formula you are interested in.

All the third-rank analogues of your formula vanish, because at least one index will turn up
an odd number of times.

Finally we get to your formula, the fourth-rank one.
Again, any time an index appears an odd number of times,
the average will vanish.
It is hopefully clear that there are only two kinds of non-vanishing form.
In the first form, all the indices are the same.
We did this case above: the answer is 
$\langle x^4\rangle = \langle y^4\rangle = \langle z^4\rangle = \frac{1}{5}$.
In the second form, two of the indices are the same, and the other two are also the same,
but different from the first two. An example is $\langle x^2 y^2 \rangle$.
Here's one way to evaluate it.
By symmetry $\langle x^2 y^2 \rangle$ and $\langle x^2 z^2 \rangle$ are equal to each other,
so we can add them together and divide by two without changing the result:
$$
\langle x^2 y^2 \rangle = \frac{1}{2}\langle x^2 (y^2+z^2) \rangle
= \frac{1}{2}\langle x^2 (1-x^2) \rangle
$$
where we used the normalization condition.
Using the previous result for $\langle x^2\rangle$ gives
$$
\langle x^2 y^2 \rangle = \frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{2} \langle x^4\rangle .
\tag{1} \label{eqn1}
$$
If we substitute $\langle x^4\rangle=\langle z^4\rangle=\frac{1}{5}$ from the integral above,
we get $\langle x^2 y^2 \rangle = \frac{1}{15}$.
The same answer applies for $\langle x^2 z^2 \rangle$, $\langle y^2 z^2 \rangle$,
and of course for $\langle xyxy \rangle$ and any other combination with two pairs of identical indices.
The formula appearing in the question simply combines together all these possibilities
in the correct way: the right hand side can only take the values $0$, $\frac{1}{15}$, or $\frac{1}{5}$,
depending on the precise choice of $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, $\delta$.

Instead of calculating the $\langle x^4\rangle$ by brute force integration, 
we can use another symmetry relation.
Suppose we rotate the coordinate system by 45 degrees about the $z$ axis,
which converts $x\rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x+y)$ and $y\rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x-y)$
without changing the answer.
It follows that
$$
\langle x^2 y^2 \rangle = \frac{1}{4} \left\langle (x+y)^2(x-y)^2\right\rangle .
$$
Expanding this, and remembering that $\langle x^4\rangle=\langle y^4\rangle$,
leads to $\langle x^4\rangle=3\langle x^2y^2\rangle$.
This may be inserted into equation \eqref{eqn1} and of course we end up with
$\langle x^2 y^2 \rangle = \frac{1}{15}$ and $\langle x^4\rangle=\frac{1}{5}$ as before.

Finally, the answer to your question

> how this will change if all dipoles have dipole moments normal to the
>   nanoparticle surface

is that *none of the above expressions will apply*.
They all rely on random dipole orientations, as stated in your question; in other words
the orientational distribution must be isotropic.
If, as you say, the dipoles are aligned normal to the surface,
this means that even the first-rank averages $\langle x\rangle$,  $\langle y\rangle$, $\langle z\rangle$
will be nonzero,
and the higher-rank averages will also reflect this lower symmetry.
Suppose the coordinate system is arranged so that the point of interest (the dipole) lies on the $z$-axis, with the centre of the nanoparticle at the origin. 
Then you can derive some relations by considering rotations about this axis
(local cylindrical symmetry).
However, the formula you have quoted only applies if you have complete rotational symmetry about *all* axes,
which will not be the case in the vicinity of the nanoparticle.
To say any more,
it is necessary to know the orientational distribution of the dipoles:
I would expect it to depend on the $\theta$ angle relative to the $z$-axis
(in the above-mentioned coordinate system) but not on the $\phi$ angle. 
If you *literally* mean that each dipole points exactly along the direction normal to the nanoparticle surface,
then actually your problem involves no orientational averaging at all
(the distribution is a perfectly sharp function, a Dirac delta function,
in orientation space). So, in that limit, things would be simpler!
In this case
$$
\left\langle (e_i^z)^4 \right\rangle = 1
$$
and all other fourth-rank terms would vanish (because the $x$ and $y$ components would vanish identically).
If you are combining fields due to all the surface dipoles,
you need to take into account that the direction of the dipole varies from place to place:
you should replace $e_i^z$ by the component of $\mathbf{e}_i$ in the radial direction.

Anyway, hopefully this explains where that formula comes from, and how the averaging works,
which was the main question.

Comment: LonelyProf thank you for your detailed explanation.